# JS output to div tag disappears immediately after appearing

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am making a basic calculator, and I want each result of the user's calculation to be shown in a div History. The problem is, whenever a calculation is done, the result appears underneath history for fractions of a second, before disappearing. The function I am using is below:

```
function sum() {
        getNumbers();
        var sum = input1 + input2;
        alert(sum);
        document.getElementById("History").innerHTML += sum;
}
```

And my full html/js code if needed:

```js
   var input1, input2

function getNumbers() {
input1 = Number(document.getElementById("imp1").value);
input2 = Number(document.getElementById("imp2").value);
}

function sum() {
 getNumbers();
 var sum = input1 + input2;
 alert(sum);
 document.getElementById("History").innerHTML += "<br>" + sum;
}

function diff() {
 getNumbers();
 var diff = input1 - input2;
  alert(diff);
  document.getElementById("History").innerHTML += "<br>" +  diff;
}

function prod() {
 getNumbers();
 var prod = input1 * input2;
 alert(prod);
 document.getElementById("History").innerHTML += "<br>" +  prod;
}

function quot() {
 getNumbers();
 var quot = input1 / input2;
 alert(quot);
 document.getElementById("History").innerHTML += "<br>" +  quot;
}
```

```html
 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="calculator.css" />
    <script src ="calculator.js"></script>
    
    
    <div id="calc">
     <form name="calc_input">
     <input type="text" id="imp1" />
     <input type="text" id="imp2" />
     <!-- buttons -->
     <button onclick="sum()" id="add" value="sum">Add</button>
     <button onclick="diff()" id="subtract" value="diff">Subtract</button>
     <button onclick="prod()" id="multiply" value="prod">Multiply</button>
     <button onclick="quot()" id="divide" value="quot">Divide</button>
    
     </form>
    </div>
    
    <div id="History">
    <p>
    History:
    
    </p>
    </div>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: you have your whole code inside head rather than the body tag

Comment: I just realized that the program actually works in the code snipper, but not in my browser. Am I missing something?

Comment: Because you paste code in snipper and snipper puts your whole code into body tag. But you put your codes into head tag, this is wrong.

Comment: had nothing to do with head/body tag, I fixed it in my code and it didnt do anything. Christopher's answer fixed my problem. Probably because the page doesn't reload with snipper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could have to do with buttons having a submit behavior by default. Probably when you click it is submitting your form and reloading the page. Try adding `type="button"` to each button.

Comment: @alec935 glad to hear! Would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: no problem, it just gives something like 10 mins before I can, thats the reason for the delay

Comment: @alec935 right! I hadn't noticed how recently you posted.  Thank you kindly and I apologize if I seemed pushy/impatient.

Comment: @Christopher worked perfectly with my project Django Form+Javascript+jQuery+bootstrap setup. Thanks